# Can't login to unix mysql user

Tags: mysql, bash, authentication, sudo

I'm trying to login to my `mysql` user created by the MySQL installation in bash shell.
So the command I'm trying to do is:

```
sudo -i -u mysql
```

But, it does **nothing** (nothing printed out in the console, not connected to any user whatsoever, etc...).
*EDIT: The return value of the command is 1 though.*

Here is the `mysql` user line in the `/etc/passwd` file:

```
mysql:x:89:89::/var/lib/mysql:/bin/false
```

I'm running on ArchLinux 64bit and the user I'm trying to connect to is local (no connection to a remote server whatsoever).

I'm trying to understand why I can login with **any** other user (like `postgres`, `root`, ...) but **not** `mysql`.

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intended behaviour. When you compare the `/etc/passwd` line with other lines you'll notice that the user `mysql` has `/bin/false` setup as the shell while others have usually `/bin/sh` or sth. similar.

When you sudo to `mysql` you actually get a login for about a millisecond or so and then his "shell" gets executed. `/bin/false` immediately returns with `rc=1` (that's the only purpose of the `false` command).

This is some kind of "trick" to prevent users from logging in as user `mysql` although the account is otherwise fully operational.

The user `mysql` may even have a valid password and be enabled but due to his odd shell setting you cannot login as him. Sometimes these *technical users* have `/usr/bin/passwd` set as their shell. Then you can only `sudo` to that user and change his password, nothing else.

Comment: Thanks! That explains a lot and I understand now why I "can't" login. But that doesn't fix my base problem, which is not really related to this question. I'm fairly new to stackoverflow, do I need to ask a question for **each** individual problems I have?

Comment: You're welcome. This was a nice question and well put. +1 for that. Especially the passwd line was helpful and showed your effort. And _yes_, please ask a new question for each individual problem. (Not only) in this way SO is different from a chat. (And thanks for giving me credits :-)

Comment: Okay! And nevermind, I found the solution to my main problem. Thanks a lot, again!